# GPL Ghostscript 9.04 build mac os x framework from source error?

Tags: macos, ghostscript

I've downloaded the ghostscript-9.04.tar.gz from http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghostscript/files/GPL%20Ghostscript/9.04/. Then I build the source as a framework just as the help document "make.html" described like this: copy macosx.mak to the top-level directory, rename it to makefile and issue 'make framework' from Terminal.app.

The procedure failed, and the information as below:

```
usermatoiMac:9.4 user$ make framework
make so-subtarget BUILDDIRPREFIX=so
make LDFLAGS=' -dynamic -dynamiclib' GS_XE=./sobin/libgs.9.04.dylib STDIO_IMPLEMENTATION=c DISPLAY_DEV=./soobj/display.dev BUILDDIRPREFIX=so CFLAGS=' -dynamic -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-builtin -fno-common -DHAVE_STDINT_H ' prefix=/Library/Frameworks/Ghostscript.framework ./sobin/gsc 
I./base -o ./soobj/aux/genconf ./base/genconf.c
make[2]: I./base: No such file or directory
make[2]: [soobj/aux/genconf] Error 1 (ignored)
I./base -o ./soobj/aux/echogs ./base/echogs.c
make[2]: I./base: No such file or directory
make[2]: [soobj/aux/echogs] Error 1 (ignored)
./soobj/aux/echogs -w ./soobj/devs.tr - -include ./soobj/unix_
make[2]: ./soobj/aux/echogs: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [soobj/devs.tr] Error 1
make[1]: *** [so-subtarget] Error 2
make: *** [so] Error 2
```

I don't know why the offical makefile can't work well, I'm a newbie for ghostscript, so I don't know how to fix this problem. Anyone can help me? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Ghostscript is now at version 9.04. Please see http://www.ghostscript.com/download to get the latest.

8.54 had support for COMPILE_INTS=1, but it was not enabled by default, so you may want to build with that so that the initialization files get put into the exectuable as compressed data. The default to COMPILE_INITS=1 didn't occur until release 8.56.

Comment: Thanks, I have noticed that I can set COMPILE_INTS=0 to compile the initialization files into the executable. But when I did that and issued 'make framework' from Terminal.app, there are 2 errors. I don't know what else I have to modify?

Answer (score 1):

I have had the exact same error with ghostscript 9.04 and 9.05.

But when I tried with ghostscript8.63, it worked as described in that tutorial.

Hope this helps! ;)